# Variation of Parameters second order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Sorry in advance for the chaotic mess. Hopefully you will be able to follow. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Given the second order ODEP: $y" + 9y = 6tan(3x)$

Find the characteristic polynomial:
$r = 0 \pm 3i$

$y_1= cos(3x)$

$y_2= sine(3x)$

$W(y_1,y_2)=3$

$-cos(3x) \int \frac{sine(3x)6sin(3x)}{3cos(3x)} + sine(3x) \int \frac{6cos(3x)sin(3x)}{3cos(3x)}$

I am unsure as to why The LHS goes from $\frac{1-cos^2(3x)}{cos(3x)}$

to $-cos(3x) \int sec(3x) - cos(3x)+ sin(3x) \int ...$

is the because the integral could be rewritten as $\int \frac{1}{cos(3x)} \times \frac{-cos^2(3x)}{cos(3x)}$ since $\frac{1}{cos(x)} = sec(3x)$

Then where does everything come from after that in the following, besides the natural log part. That is straight forward.

$\frac{-cos(3t)}{3}(\ln \vert sec(3x) + tan(3x) \vert - sin(3x)$

$-sin(3t)$ and the three in the denominator of $cos(3x)$?

Why is the 6 not included in the integrals as G(x)?

and finally I don't understand where $\int sin(3x)$ goes to

$\frac{sin(3x)}{3} \times -cos(3x)$?